# How can I find heapsize used by neo4j in my server

Tags: cakephp, neo4j, heap-size

How can I find how much memory is neo4j using on in server. I know min and max memory that I have defined. I want to know the current usage. I am using Everyman Lib in my cakephp code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle JDK ships with a nice tool called jVisualVM, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/ for details.

When starting up you can attach to local running java processes, select the one for Neo4j. This gives you access to a lot of JVM internal information, memory consumption is one of them.